# Как на Go узнать имя текущего пользователя Windows?

Tags: windows, golang

Требуется в golang на windows узнать имя сейчас использующегося пользователя

Comment: Пакет `os/user`, функция [`user.Current()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/user#Current). Работает в Linux/Unix/Mac, Windows, Android. В Windows возвращает строку вида ` WORKSTATION\User`.

Answer (score 1):

В языке программирования Go имеется пакет [os/user](https://pkg.go.dev/os/user), в котором имеется метод `Current`, возвращающий текущего пользователя.

Пример использования:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/user"
)

func main() {
    user, err := user.Current()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Printf("Username: %s\n", user.Username)
}
```